# Is there a word that means "to walk slowly"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

The only word that comes to my mind is *tiptoe*. However, this word implies that you are walking stealthily or cautiously.

Is there a word that just means *to walk slowly*?

Example sentence:

> Without knowing what I was doing, I _ toward her.

Comment: Hmm. Is it essential that the word provided means "walk"? Or can it just mean "move"? My feeling is that "drifted" fits very nicely, but that doesn't mean "walk" at all.

Comment: Tiptoe doesn't have to be slow.  Check out ballerinas, for example.

Comment: how about 'creep' -> 'crept' since it's in the past -- Without knowing what I was doing, I was creeping toward her. (there's a bit of fearful/stealthy feeling in the word 'creep' though); How about 'careen' ?  (especially when you're drunk) -> Walk as if unable to control one's movements -- Without knowing what I was doing, I was careening toward her.

Comment: Was he daydreaming? Why is "walked slowly" not appropriate here? Please give as much information as possible: the guidance in the full tag info will help here.

Comment: @AndyT has exactly my question.  Many of the other answers presented are ways of describing a  more deliberate, and even perhaps a stylized gait, and while 'drifted' does not mean walk, it fits a the 'without knowing what i was doing' sense of a unconscious movement.

Comment: Mosey on down (not actually vpeculiar to US, commonly heard in UK). Waddle, amble, pootle, footer, shamble, saunter, traipse, toddle, sidle, sloth, slough, slope, inch, edge, shift ...

Comment: When my kids take their time getting out of or into the car, I generally entreat them not to ***lollygag*** but it doesn't necessarily fit here.  Still, it's an enjoyable word.

Comment: mincing along would connote short steps

Comment: When you say “just means _to walk slowly_”, do you mean with as few other connotations as possible? Or do you want to suggest something more.

Comment: @AndyT: If water is not involved I would take “_drifted_” to mean moved slowly by whatever means make sense in the context, which could easily mean walking.

Comment: @PeterPoint - yeeessss... but it also connotates ["with short, *affectedly* dainty steps"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mince?s=t). If you're doing anything *affectedly* it's not "without knowing what you're doing".

Comment: I like 'migrated'?

Comment: There are so many possible answers, with different shades of meaning, that it's hard to pick one - I think we need a bit more context than the single sentence.  The only clue we have is that it's unintentional, so perhaps "drifted" is good, or maybe "edged".

Comment: @Araucaria - for some reason the word "pootled" makes me crack up. Is that actually used in the UK? It's gotta be a slang word, right?

Comment: ...whatever you do, don't Cosby toward her.

Comment: alex - Please don't feel that you have to accept suggested edits. @RustyDobbs made an edit that was wholly inappropriate, and should have been an answer (and in fact already is).

Comment: @AndyT I see. I thought the suggested edits were made by SE admins ...

Comment: @alex - No, not at all. Anyone can suggest an edit. If it's by anyone with under 2000 rep it requires approval (either by 2 people with over 2000 rep, or by the post's author). Once someone is over 2000 rep the change is instantaneous without approval, but can always be undone or changed again by the same process. Admins have a little diamond after their name; see the "Protected" banner on your question where the diamond tells you Andrew Leach is one of our moderators on ELU.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

I would suggest **[amble](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/amble)**:

> *verb*
>
> 1. to go at a slow, easy pace; stroll; saunter:
>
> *noun*
>
> 4. a slow, easy walk or gentle pace.

<sup>dictionary.com</sup>

Your sentence would then be:

> Without knowing what I was doing, I **ambled** toward her.

As that definition suggests, **strolled** or **sauntered** may also work for you.

Comment: "ambled **toward** her" or "ambled **towards** her"?

Comment: @HimabinduBoddupalli - [Either is acceptable](http://grammarist.com/spelling/toward-towards/), I just used what OP wrote.

Comment: No problem. I admit I hadn't even thought about it until you asked, and I realised both sounded fine to me and had to google to find out which was right.

Comment: strolled -upvote because I intended to include in my answer too

Comment: Meaning is correct, however I can't help but think about it without thinking of a cowboy (perhaps described in a US wild west novel) walking with a laconic swagger across a saloon.  Even if used in the modern era, 'amble' means a bit of a deliberate theatricality of slowness to me. As much attitude as talking a bit longer.

Comment: @Tom22 - To me, "amble" conjures up an image of a pleasant stroll in the countryside, but each to their own.

Comment: I was going to suggest saunter, but I see it in your answer.

Comment: @AidanO - I have "saunter" more as an aside than as a real answer. If you would like to research it and provide an answer with a suitable dictionary definition, then go ahead. I'd upvote it.

Comment: When someone saunters over to you, it's usually done with their 'other' brain; the OP's context, and the real answer here. +1@ AidanO

Comment: Not sure if its a descended word or a parent, but "perambulate" would certainly be related to "amble"  Is also the parent word to "Pram" as in baby carriage, which may suit the need.

Comment: @Himabindu *Towards* is more British English,  and *toward* is more American English. I suggest you look them both up in Oxford dictionary.

Comment: @Clare It was mentioned in the link that was posted as a reply to my question.

Comment: Okay, @Himabindu but most "21st-century British writing" that I've read that is found in novels and/or literature (and I'm guessing journalism also) has used *towards*, so it still seems/feels a strong marker of being British English.

Comment: I'd only add "trundled" as mentioned by @Orangesandlemons below

Comment: @jeffmcneill - And your reason for posting that comment on my answer is...? Are you suggesting I add it to my answer? I'm quite happy with my answer as it is - it reflects what *I* think are suitable words. If you like Orangesandlemons's answer feel free to upvote it. The current consensus of both the community and the OP is that "ambled" is more suitable than "trundled".

Comment: @RustyDobbs - I have no idea if this message will ping to you or not, but if you like the answer "stroll" then all you need to do is find it on this page and upvote it, or if it's not already there then add it yourself. Editing it into the question, or making a suggested edit on the accepted answer is not the way forward! Once you gain some rep (by actually asking and answering questions yourself, rather than editing others') you'll be able to post comments.

Comment: Thank you @AndyT for letting us know how to upvote others' answers. A perspecacious editor would likely improve their answer with additional options. As we know in English, there are many words, and suitability might be a distribution rather than a binary result.

Comment: @jeffmcneill - Great idea. Why don't I just copy everybody's answers, and put them all in my post? Then no-one will need to vote on other answers separately, giving their feedback as to which they prefer. </sarcasm> I am aware that suitability is a distribution and not just a binary result. Those other answers which I like I have upvoted; those I think are wrong I have downvoted; those I am ambivalent about I have left. It's the stackexchange model...

Comment: Well, definitely take heed from good answers, even if they are not your own. That's not copying, that's just good sense. Complaining about good comments, not very sensible. Shut your yap, if you have nothing more to contribute.

Answer (score 47):

Depends on what **kind** of a slow walk you are looking for.

Plod (verb)

> walk doggedly and slowly with heavy steps.

e.g. She plodded into the kitchen after a tiresome day.

Lumber (verb)

> move in a slow, heavy, awkward way.

Shamble (verb)

> (of a person) move with a slow, shuffling, awkward gait.

So the answer would be, "Without knowing what I was doing, I plodded/shambled/lumbered towards her".

Comment: That is more than one answer.  Please post each separately.

Comment: @Chenmunka - Since when has that been a rule?

Comment: @Chenmunka The questioner hasn't mentioned the exact **kind** of a slow walk, hence, I have listed the possibilities. They aren't the same. There are nuances in the meaning conveyed by each of the words.

Comment: Exactly my point.  They are three separate answers.  Posting separately allows the OP to select the one that best suits them.

Comment: @AndyT : It turns out that in general, the consensus is in favour of separate answers. 
 https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/should-we-encourage-posting-distinct-answers-separately-particularly-for-sing .

Comment: While I'm not fond of multiple answers myself,  when the answer lays out the different usage of very different words they're much better with me - or alternatively if they are for nearly the same way to address a way of expressing things.  An answer posted as a situational possibility is better for me than an answer proposed without qualification of when it should be chosen

Comment: @MartinBonner - thank you for that link. It seems that each SE has its own way of doing things, which is kind of confusing actually.

Comment: How about Trudging? :)

Comment: @DirkvB That has been mentioned as an answer by Masked Man. Please scroll down to have a look at it.

Answer (score 27):

[Dawdle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dawdle):

> move slowly and idly in a particular direction.

<sup>en.oxforddictionaries.com</sup>

This is the word I would use.

Comment: This one works for me, even though dawdle means as much absence of concerted effort and perhaps delay, as its moving definition.  It works  better with the 'without knowing what I was doing' example, and would also work better with someone described as moving annoyingly slowly but not in a deliberate style.

Comment: Ian-  Your answer will likely be better accepted by the community if you include a reference for your answer.  Online dictionaries work well.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Ian.  FYI- Feel free to make edits to your answer as you see fit to improve its usefulness.  Just click edit.

Comment: dawdled towards her does not make sense. Dawdling is dawdling and takes no object. I can't understand why this got so many upvotes.

Comment: While it seems some (not even all!) dictionaries have a definition that includes movement like this, I haven't seen it used in that way. It's much more common for *dawdle* to imply, if anything, a *lack* of movement (at least towards the end goal).

Comment: Dawdle doesn't describe walking specifically, even by connotation. It's all sorts of actions that delay movement towards a goal; when a small child is dawdling, they may be crawling, they may be investigating a toy instead of going to get ready for bed, etc. It *can* describe walking slowly, but that's only one of a set of things it describes.

Comment: Not definitive by any means, but in the Southern US states, I've generally heard "dawdle" used as NOT moving, or maybe just moving extremely slowly.

Answer (score 25):

If it's done in a relaxed and leisurely manner, then you "moseyed toward her".

From [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mosey):

> **to walk or go slowly, usually without a special purpose:**
>
> *I'll just mosey on down to the beach for a while*.

I'd say the closest synonym is "saunter" (and it's the first word I thought of when I came across this question but saw that I'd been beaten to it) and I'd also say it's perhaps more common in AmE than BrE.

Comment: this one, like 'amble' seems far too 'us western' ... whether that was it's origin or not, it became almost a comic reference as I hear it used.

Comment: Yeah, I looked it up a bit further and it's definitely an 'Old West' era sort of word.

Comment: I like mosey a hell of a lot better than amble.

Comment: *mosey* implies more conscious intent than the question, and has a significantly more "western" feel, as others have pointed out.

Comment: @Kevin sure, I'm not trying to hide that but the level of intent implied is debatable

Comment: I vote for this one. I live in Texas, and down here we mosey all the time.

Answer (score 21):

Strolled.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stroll

Definition #2:

> to walk in a leisurely or idle manner

Answer (score 20):

My proposes:

> Without knowing what I was doing, I **drifted** toward her.

[with adverbial of direction] Walk slowly, aimlessly, or casually. [Definition from Oxford Dictionary](http://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drift)

> Without knowing what I was doing, I **tended** toward her.

[no object, with adverbial] Go or move in a particular direction. [Definition from Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tend)

**Edit**

I do agree that the second usage is very rare, so maybe a better option would be

> I **tended to move** toward her

Comment: @1006a Edited, thank you for finding better references

Comment: ▲ for **drifted**, but both **tended** and **tended to move** are considerably off the mark. They do not indicate slowness, and suggest to me that while the overall tendency is toward her there may well be variation.

Comment: I think _drifted_ is the best answer as it is consistent with _without knowing_, all of the other answers require more awareness from the narrator.

Comment: Agree with @PJTraill. *Drifted* fits the usage here perfectly, but *tended [to move]* very much does not. +1 for the former, -1 for the latter = no vote from me. Incidentally, this is why some suggest posting each suggestion as a separate answer.

Answer (score 19):

I would suggest **[gravitated](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/amble)**:

> *verb*
>
> 1. move towards or be attracted to a person or thing. "young western Europeans will gravitate to Berlin"
> 2. [**physics**] move, or tend to move, towards a centre of gravity or other attractive force.

<sup>https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=gravitated&oq=gravitated</sup>

Your sentence would then be:

> Without knowing what I was doing, I **gravitated** toward her.

Or it may suit to extend the orbit theme with:

> Without knowing what I was doing, I **gravitated** into her sphere of influence.

There's an implication that your character's path is altered by proximity to her, and that the closer their proximity, the faster they move/quicker things happen.  This allusion to orbital mechanics may suit your story.

Note there's a follow-on that gravitating too close may lead to a collision.  Depending on rest of the story, this may be seen as foreshadowing the impact/destruction of one's way of life/all dinosaurs on earth.

Comment: *Gravitated* is the best word for the given sentence.

Answer (score 17):

How about **[sidle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sidle)**?

> *intransitive v.*
>
> To advance in an unobtrusive, furtive, or coy way: swindlers who sidle up to tourists.
>
> — [wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/sidle)

In your sentence:

> Without knowing what I was doing, I *sidled* toward her.

Examples from the [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sidle) page:

> He sidled up to me and slipped me a note.
>
> She sidled over and whispered, “Do you see that guy?”.

Comment: Disagree. By that definition, "sidle" is suggested to be a very deliberate action, and not something you'd do "without knowing what you were doing".

Comment: @jsheeran I regard 'unobtrusive' and 'coy' as the most important words in the definition, that is, something you'd do in a shy manner. I think this fits as with something you'd do without knowing.

Comment: hahaha. What a hoot.

Answer (score 9):

Slightly lateral:  when we tell our dog to "sit and stay," but he **inches** (oops, there's another possibility! :-) ) towards us, we call it "**worming**" .

Comment: Inching sounds like a good idea. Can you add a dictionary definition?

Comment: squidge/ squadge/squnch are all related variants of inch, with the implication of moving like an inchworm or caterpillar.

Answer (score 9):

[Trudge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trudge) may be suitable in some contexts.

> Trudge: to walk or march steadily and usually laboriously

Answer (score 7):

[Amble](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/Amble)

> Amble: to go at a slow, easy pace

[Traipse](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/Traipse)

> Traipse: to walk or go aimlessly or idly or without finding or reaching one's goal

[Mope](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/Mope)

> Mope: to move or act in an aimless way

[Linger](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/Linger)

> Linger: to walk slowly

[Drift](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/Drift)

> Drift: to wander aimlessly

[Dilly-dally](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/Dilly-dally)

> Dilly-dally: To idle; dither in an aimless or pointless fashion

[Meander](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/Meander)

> Meander: to wander aimlessly

[Wander](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/Wander)

> Wander: to go aimlessly, indirectly, or casually

Comment: You do know that almost a bunch of these words mostly don't work in that sentence, right? You would never *linger* toward someone.

Comment: "Dilly-dally", "mope" and "linger" don't really work, but I guess the others could.

Answer (score 7):

'**Saunter**' has been mentioned but I feel it deserves a proper answer. It's the word I immediately thought of.

> to walk about in an idle or leisurely manner

-[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saunter)

> to walk in a slow and relaxed way, often in no particular direction

-[Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/saunter)

Answer (score 5):

[***Trundle***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trundle) is pretty much perfect for this. In this case, "trundled towards"

from oxforddictionaries.com definition 1.1 :

> (of a person) move heavily and slowly. ‘she heard him coughing as he
>   trundled out’

Comment: Please quote the relevant definition of that word here, and mention the source by name.

Comment: Generally 'trundle' involves wheels - hence trundle bed.  I notice you didn't pick definition 1.  Imho, that kinda makes trundle not 'pretty much perfect'.

Comment: @mcalex I don't see why other uses, even predominant uses, would stop something from being perfect in the context.

Answer (score 4):

[Dandered](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dander) - Verb

> (Ulster) To walk along with no particular haste.
>
> *To dander along the beach.*
>
> **Synonyms**
>
> - bimble
> - stroll
> - wander

<sup>en.wiktionary.org</sup>

Comment: Please mention the source by name, and include a link to it if it is available online.

Answer (score 4):

The [dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/edge) I often use gives edged. I like that because that is the way I would approach the edge of a cliff.

> To move gradually or hesitantly: *The child edged toward the door.*

<sup>thefreedictionary.com</sup>

It introduces an element of danger or fear. Of course it would depend on the context.

Comment: Aled - please cite your sources, otherwise you breach copyright. If they're online ones please also add a link. I've edited this answer for you, please consider doing the same for your other answers if relevant.

Answer (score 4):

[shuffle](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shuffle) -  1. To walk without lifting the feet or with clumsy steps and a shambling gait.

> Without knowing what I was doing, I **shuffled** toward her.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised nobody has mentioned **crawl** yet:

> to move slowly with the body close to the ground ; the time we had to crawl through a narrow passageway from one cave to another

or

> to move slowly ; the weekend traffic on the road to the beach just crawled

Comment: Crawl might work with to 'move' slowly, but not to 'walk' slowly.

Comment: If you put it in the sentence "I crawled towards her" it sounds more like you're crawling on all fours like a baby, or fully prone in a "commando crawl".

Answer (score 1):

**Stalked**
verb (used without object)

1. to pursue or approach prey, quarry, etc., stealthily.
2. to walk with measured, stiff, or haughty strides: 
   He was so angry he stalked away without saying goodbye.

Like several other answers here, this one will depend heavily on the context of the movement as to whether this is the appropriate type of movement.

Comment: And with it bring all the implied meanings of being a stalker. Not good.

Comment: @marcellothearcane: This answer does say it depends on the context — **stalked** might just be spot-on!

Comment: @PJTraill *everything* depends on context. Granted, maybe the OP was looking for a stalker-esque word, but the fact that they have accepted 'amble' (which indicates that it helped *them*) I doubt it. It might be helpful for other people though...

Comment: @PJTraill You could stalk something - say an animal in a forest - by quietly sprinting from behind one tree to another. It definitely does mean "pursue stealthily" (as per defn), but doesn't really imply slowly - unless you are slowly stalking! I don't think this answers the question, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is **[skulk](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/skulk)**:

> To move about stealthily.

<sup>thefreedictionary.com</sup>

However it does carry a connotation of sneaking out of shame or embarassment.  I wouldn't use it if the primary underlying factor is subconscious attraction, but I might if I were trying to additionally impart the subject with shyness or social awkwardness.

Comment: HonoredMule - please cite your sources, otherwise you breach copyright. If they're online ones please also add a link. I've edited this answer for you, please consider doing the same for your other answers if relevant.

Comment: Citing sources does not mean one is not breaching copyright.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström - I never said it did. I'm not a copyright expert, but [www.copyrightservice.co.uk](https://www.copyrightservice.co.uk/copyright/p09_fair_use) does say that fair use may be possible provided "that the source of the quoted material is mentioned". If you're not citing your source then you *definitely* fall foul of that. If you do cite your source then, with the length of extracts we tend to post on this site, I believe we are generally ok.

Answer (score 1):

For *walk slowly* I like **Perambulate**:

> walk or travel through or around a place or area, especially for pleasure > and in a leisurely way.

(similar to meander and saunter)

Though this, and many other answers here, seem to convey a sort of intentional type of slow movement.  Your sentence example, wherein the subject seems hypnotized, lends itself more to *drift* (as is mentioned in AndyT's comment) or perhaps *float*?

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/perambulate

Answer (score 0):

For me the word that fits is - sashay. 
From Wordnik 
'intransitive v. To walk or proceed, especially in an easy or casual manner.'
But the accepted answer is fine too. It all depends on the ambience.

Comment: *Sashay* is [to strut, swagger or flounce](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sashay). It's also got a feminine overtone to it.

Comment: @tchrist - the full definition from your source is "(intransitive) To walk casually or showily; to strut, swagger or flounce.  [quotations ▼]". Is there a reason to omit the relevant bit?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the short answer all - I'm more used to Stack Overflow where short answers are treated like royalty :D

Better response:

I still like meander as it has a whimsical connotation - which the provided example seems to be wanting. It was pointed out that prance has an energy to it that makes it incompatible but shuffled is still a decent option, though a bit defeated sounding for OP's example...

Stepped is still workable - just a bit dull.

I would say of my previous suggestions, meander holds up the best.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Not prance. Prancing is leaping sprightly, with 'springy' steps - not slow walking.

Comment: You might want to include actual definitions or, at the very least, links to definitions in online dictionaries.  I usually use the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/).

Comment: Y'all are picky over here!! Joking, joking. If someone in stack overflow wanted the definition of basic linguistic principle in Python we'd generally tell them to go learn the fundamentals of the language then come back and ask. I assume most users are at least fluent in the language yes? Maybe just a different culture but most SO users are expert or near so we wouldn't define simple terms or define principles which should be understood prior to asking for help - I'm new here and trying to learn ;)

Comment: **Meandering** is not just slow but also varying in direction or even undirected.

Comment: You give your opinions on the words, but not how they actually work. Imagine answering a question about what function to chose and saying "print might be what you want but it's a bit dull". I don't think people would find that too helpful. For a [tag:single-word-requests] answer, you need to explain how the word you suggest works in the given context. Why would you pick any of the words you suggest over another. Certainly *dullness* could be a criteria, but I think in this context the shades of nuance in meaning are more pertinent.